# Ryanair visa check with two passports

Tags: visas, passports, ryanair, biometric-passports, ukrainian-citizens

I have a residency of Ukraine and two valid passports. One is an old non-biometric, and the new one biometric. In a few months I have a flight from Ukraine to Germany and from Germany to Morocco with Ryanair. Both flights booked using my new passport data. I am allowed to enter Germany (and other Schengen countries) without visa using my new biometric passport (and so I will). However I need a visa for Morocco and let's assume I have it in my other passport. I assume there will be no problems with the border authorities, but what about Ryanair visa check before my Germany - Morocco flight? Is it ok to have a plane ticket booked using one passport and having my visa in another?

*UPD:*

My question is rather will there be any problems on Ryanair visa check with two passports (one with the visa in it and another used for ticket booking), than just about travelling with two passports.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. As long as you carry both passports with you (and present also the other one in case anyone asks) I do not see any problems.

Comment: Related but not quite a duplicate https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52100/58919

Comment: @mts Yes, I think so as well. Just wandering maybe someone was in similar situation and may share the experience. I haven't found any evidence that this is allowed or prohibited in Ryanair travel documentation. So I have a doubt if they can charge me for changing the passport number in the ticket or smth else on the visa check desk.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk Well, the link you mentioned describes travelling with passports of two different countries. My case is a bit different.

Comment: @Giorgio Not a duplicate. He asks what to do with two passports from the same country.

Comment: @ThorstenS It doesn't matter if the passports are from different countries or the same country, the answer still applies.  Ryanair also does not charge fees for changing passport info, as long as the name stays the same.

Comment: Ryanair ask for a visa check for anyone that doesn't have an EEA passport, my partner is American and they ask it for hers when travelling to Europe even tho she travels visa free, all they do is write or stamp your ticket that your passport has been checked, they do nothing with a computer or anything. Can be annoying if theres a big queue, but you just go to the check in gate.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming, since we are talking Ryanair, that you have two separate tickets. Unless the policy has changed, they do *not* offer connecting flights on a single ticket, and they do *not* guarantee the connection. What this means, for your question, is that the first Ryanair agent will not care about your visa into Morocco, only whether you can be admitted into Germany.

Obviously you will need to take both passports, so that later you can get into Morocco.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you must take both passports with you. If you have no obligation to do the check in online, do it at the airport and explain your situation showing both passports

Comment: But Ryanair charges like €50 extra per flight if you don't check in online...